# Transforming observed Fisher information

Tags: mathematical-statistics, likelihood, fisher-information

Let $x_1$,$x_2$,....$x_n$ be a random sample from the exponential distribution with p.d.f.:
$$f(x;\lambda)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\;\;\;x\geq0\;\;\;\lambda>0$$
The log-likelihood is:
$$l(\lambda)=nlog(\lambda)-\lambda \sum x_i$$
The maximum likelihood estimate for $\lambda$ is:
$$\hat{\lambda}=\frac{n}{\sum x_i}$$
The observed information is:
$$j(\hat{\lambda})=\frac{n}{\hat{\lambda}^2}$$

Now, be $\mu=\mu(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\lambda}$ a reparametrization of the model.
The log-likelihood is:
$$l(\mu)=-nlog(\mu)-\frac{n\bar{x}}{\mu}$$
The maximum likelihood estimate for $\mu$ is:
$$\hat{\mu}=\frac{\sum x_i}{n}$$
The observed information is:
$$j(\hat{\mu})=-\frac{n}{\hat{\mu}^2}+\frac{2n\bar{x}}{\hat{\mu}^3} \;\;\;[1]$$ 
As far as I know, the observed information in the new parametrization $\mu$ can be calculated with this formula:
$$j(\hat{\mu})=j(\hat{\lambda})(\lambda'(\hat{\mu}))^2$$
I tried to use this formula to calculate the observed information of the new parametrization $j(\hat{\mu})$ from the observed information of the old parametrization but I get a different result than [1]. Am I missing something?

Comment: This post does not seem to make a consistent distinction between a parameter and its estimate.  As such, the formulae for the [observed information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observed_information) *appear* to be expressed in terms of free variables ($\lambda$ and $\mu$) rather than in terms of the data. It's unclear how much of that is typographical errors (such as the loss of a negative sign in the formula for $f$) and how much might be conceptual, so please check your post carefully to ensure it expresses precisely what you intend.

Comment: I've corrected the pdf. I honestly don't know what's wrong with the observed informations.  As far as I know, the observed information is the negative of the second derivative of the log-likelihood, which can be evaluated at the maximum-likelihood estimate or expressed as a function of the true parameter

Comment: There's an ambiguity in the usage. There's not much else to do with the observed information function except evaluate it at the MLE, so talk of "the observed information" usually implies that's what you've done. I say "the observed information function" if I don't want to imply that.

Comment: I see. I've edited the answer. I hope it's clear now

Comment: That helps--but you do need to do the algebra if you would like to make any progress.  Substitute the explicit formulae for $\hat\lambda$ and $\hat\mu$ into the observed information expressions, and only then compare them.